# reference to another class on initialization

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I have a class who do some things.

```
class ClassA
{

public:
    ClassA()
    { 
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < MAX_PROCESS_ID; ++i) 
            processDB[i] = 0; 
    };

    virtual ~ClassA(){ };

    int     create(int pID);
    bool    check(int pID);
    bool    kill(int pID);
    int     returnpDB(int pID);

private:
    bool saveProcess(int pID, int type);

protected:
    int pDB[MAX_PROCESS_ID];
};
```

and what i want to do it's initialize this class from another one and keep a reference.

for example:

```
class classB
{

public:
    classB(){};
    virtual ~classB(){ };

private:

protected:
    classA      &pm;
};
```

how can i do this? (if I can!)

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class classB
{

public:
    classB(classA& ref):pm(ref){};
    virtual ~classB(){ };

private:

protected:
    classA      &pm;
};
```

Comment: thanks!, 
a last question:
Now I'm calling the class on my MAIN doing:

classB b;
classA a(b);

there is a way to just call classA a; and create the ref to classB inside the class code?

Comment: you can declare a default object for classA say:`static classA default_obj;` and give it to the empty constructor, or use it as default to the existing constructor. like: `classB(classA& ref=default_obj):pm(ref){}`